# $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R}, \exists M, N \in \mathbb{Z}^*$ such that $Ma=Nb$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Is this true including irrational numbers for $a$ and $b$ (excluding the trivial case of $M = N = 0$)?

Comment: Just take $M=N=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a trick.

In general it wouldn't be true.  If, for example, of $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational.  Then $Ma$ would be rational, and $Nb$ would not be rational, if $N \ne 0$.

ANd if $a,b,N,M$ are not zero then $Ma = Nb \iff \frac ab = \frac NM$ and the RHS must be rational and $a,b$ are under no such obligation.

But the question never said we can't have $M, N$ be $0$.

And if $M=0; N=0$ then $Ma = Nb = 0$ for all $a,b$.  So that certainly makes it true.

Comment: I think the OP meant non zero integers here

Comment: If the OP meant that the OP had to say that.   And I covered that issue thoroughly I thought.

Comment: I definitely meant to exclude the trivial case of $M = N = 0$.